# SSIS Filtering records from flat file

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to filter records in flat file that conatin string **"Order"** and then import result to the excel file.

I used the **Conditional Split** component for this with condition FINDSTRING(MyColumn,"Order",1) > 0 but it does not work - no record is imported as result.

Rows in my flat file looks  like this: `2020-01-01 11:51:00 3459 Order:1398 session:fr34skjdnn32kjsd ID:67889`

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

The code below is only a sample of how to read the file.  I would need to see more lines of the input to get code to work with any input.  I've been parsing text files like this for over 45 years and have learned that ONE row of input is never sufficient to get code like this to work with ALL inputs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order order = new Order();
            List<Order> orders = order.ReadFile(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string order { get; set; }
        public string session { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        public List<Order> ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Order newOrder = new Order();
                orders.Add(newOrder);
                string dateStr = line.Substring(0, 24);
                newOrder.date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                string pattern = @"(?'key'[^:]+):(?'value'[^\s]+)";
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line.Substring(24), pattern);

                foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>().AsEnumerable())
                {
                    string key = match.Groups["key"].Value.Trim();
                    string value = match.Groups["value"].Value.Trim();

                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case "Order" :
                            newOrder.order = value;
                            break;

                        case "session":
                            newOrder.session = value;
                            break;

                        case "ID" :
                            newOrder.id = value;
                            break;


                    }
                }
            }
            return orders;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my flat file word  "Order"  occurs mainly in front of a colon or in quotation marks, for example: row1: 2020-01-01 11:51:00 3459 Order:1398 session:fr34skjdkjhu7jsd ID:67889     row2:  2020-01-01 11:51:00 3459 'Order' 1398 session:fr34skjdnn32kjsd ID:67869  and some cases look like this: row3: 2020-01-01 11:51:00 3459 'Order 1398 session:fr34jhgbukybhj7kjsd ID:67879. So we have only 3 cases: Order:, 'Order', 'Order . There are a lot of lines without "Order" but I want to have as a result rows only with this word.

Comment: This looks like hand type data with lots of inconsistencies why make it very hard to parse.  I would need to see a lot more lines of data to do a proper job.  This looks like a final project that I did in college where the professor had typo errors in the input to make the project challenging.  We had to write code on PUNCH CARDS and ended up with over 500 cards written in FORTRAN and had more card in the waste basket than in the final project.